# My code Runs correctly but crashes when Debugging

Tags: android

The following is part of my code, when I run it in Android Studio, it works correctly,

```
if(actInfo.size()>0){
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listOfTimes);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, actInfo);
    adapter.setClickListener(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

but when I debug it, the app crashes in the forth line:
`adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, actInfo);`

I puutted a Try & Catch to catch the problem:

```
    if(actInfo.size()>0){
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listOfTimes);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        try {
            adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, actInfo);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.v("TAG1:",e.toString());}

        adapter.setClickListener(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

but Try Catch is not catching the exception and it's not working.
What is the problem?

this is Log:

```
07-21 14:47:48.236 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/jdwp/jdwp_event.cc:661] Check failed: Thread::Current() != GetDebugThread() (Thread::Current()=0xacc0a400, GetDebugThread()=0xacc0a400) Expected event thread
07-21 14:47:48.255 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] Runtime aborting...
07-21 14:47:48.255 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] Aborting thread:
07-21 14:47:48.255 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "JDWP" prio=5 tid=4 WaitingForDebuggerSend
07-21 14:47:48.255 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c6a9d0 self=0xacc0a400
07-21 14:47:48.255 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=24589 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb1152920
07-21 14:47:48.255 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=2 stm=9 core=0 HZ=100
07-21 14:47:48.255 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0xb1056000-0xb1058000 stackSize=1014KB
07-21 14:47:48.255 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes= "abort lock"
07-21 14:47:48.255 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc 00572f1e  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+238)
07-21 14:47:48.255 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 0053f30e  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+526)
07-21 14:47:48.255 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 0053c30b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+75)
07-21 14:47:48.255 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 00527f13  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState10DumpThreadERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEPNS_6ThreadE+67)
07-21 14:47:48.255 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 00527ce7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+615)
07-21 14:47:48.255 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 0051822b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEPKc+155)
07-21 14:47:48.255 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 0011a5b3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD1Ev+1747)
07-21 14:47:48.255 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #07 pc 0039b74d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState24AcquireJdwpTokenForEventEy+733)
07-21 14:47:48.255 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #08 pc 0039acf3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState29SendRequestAndPossiblySuspendEPNS0_9ExpandBufENS0_17JdwpSuspendPolicyEy+211)
07-21 14:47:48.255 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #09 pc 003a0ec9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState16PostClassPrepareEPNS_6mirror5ClassE+1705)
07-21 14:47:48.255 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #10 pc 001c2a85  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3Dbg16PostClassPrepareEPNS_6mirror5ClassE+53)
07-21 14:47:48.255 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #11 pc 001689fc  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11DefineClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcjNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEERKNS_7DexFileERKNS9_8ClassDefE+1116)
07-21 14:47:48.255 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #12 pc 001683e9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker26FindClassInPathClassLoaderERNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_6ThreadEPKcjNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEEPPNS8_5ClassE+1865)
07-21 14:47:48.255 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #13 pc 0016979b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker9FindClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEE+1163)
07-21 14:47:48.255 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #14 pc 005a7a7a  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier12RegTypeCache12ResolveClassEPKcPNS_6mirror11ClassLoaderE+186)
07-21 14:47:48.255 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #15 pc 005a742d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier12RegTypeCache4FromEPNS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEPKcb+701)
07-21 14:47:48.255 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #16 pc 005a70fd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier12RegTypeCache14FromDescriptorEPNS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEPKcb+77)
07-21 14:47:48.255 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #17 pc 005862ed  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier26ResolveClassAndCheckAccessEj+173)
07-21 14:47:48.255 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #18 pc 005895aa  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier25CodeFlowVerifyInstructionEPj+10970)
07-21 14:47:48.255 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #19 pc 00585f96  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier20CodeFlowVerifyMethodEv+358)
07-21 14:47:48.255 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #20 pc 00581c9d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier14VerifyCodeFlowEv+973)
07-21 14:47:48.255 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #21 pc 0057da56  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier6VerifyEv+854)
07-21 14:47:48.255 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #22 pc 0057c742  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier12VerifyMethodEPNS_6ThreadEjPKNS_7DexFileENS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEENS7_INS8_11ClassLoaderEEEPKNS4_8ClassDefEPKNS4_8CodeItemEPNS_9ArtMethodEjPNS_17CompilerCallbacksEbNS_11LogSeverityEbPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNSO_11char_traitsIcEENSO_9allocatorIcEEEE+226)
07-21 14:47:48.255 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #23 pc 0057c1c7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier13VerifyMethodsILb0EEENS1_11FailureDataEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_11ClassLinkerEPKNS_7DexFileEPKNS8_8ClassDefEPNS_21ClassDataItemIteratorENS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEENSG_INSH_11ClassLoaderEEEPNS_17CompilerCallbacksEbNS_11LogSeverityEbPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNSP_11char_traitsIcEENSP_9allocatorIcEEEE+791)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #24 pc 0057b1f9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier11VerifyClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFileENS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEENS7_INS8_11ClassLoaderEEEPKNS4_8ClassDefEPNS_17CompilerCallbacksEbNS_11LogSeverityEPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNSJ_11char_traitsIcEENSJ_9allocatorIcEEEE+921)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #25 pc 0057a4b9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier11VerifyClassEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_6mirror5ClassEPNS_17CompilerCallbacksEbNS_11LogSeverityEPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNSA_11char_traitsIcEENSA_9allocatorIcEEEE+841)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #26 pc 00174386  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11VerifyClassEPNS_6ThreadENS_6HandleINS_6mirror5ClassEEENS_11LogSeverityE+2102)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #27 pc 0017a406  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker15InitializeClassEPNS_6ThreadENS_6HandleINS_6mirror5ClassEEEbb+326)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #28 pc 00158dde  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker17EnsureInitializedEPNS_6ThreadENS_6HandleINS_6mirror5ClassEEEbb+222)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #29 pc 001b60da  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL17GetFieldValueImplEyyyPNS_4JDWP9ExpandBufEb+1866)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #30 pc 001b667e  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3Dbg19GetStaticFieldValueEyyPNS_4JDWP9ExpandBufE+78)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #31 pc 003a4c5d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWPL12RT_GetValuesEPNS0_9JdwpStateEPNS0_7RequestEPNS0_9ExpandBufE+141)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #32 pc 003a2ea4  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState14ProcessRequestEPNS0_7RequestEPNS0_9ExpandBufEPb+1044)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #33 pc 003ab570  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState12HandlePacketEv+192)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #34 pc 00678df3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP12JdwpAdbState15ProcessIncomingEv+1139)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #35 pc 003ab9d1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState3RunEv+593)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #36 pc 003aae50  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWPL15StartJdwpThreadEPv+48)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #37 pc 00074fe2  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+210)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #38 pc 0002029e  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+30)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #39 pc 0001e076  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   (no managed stack frames)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held: thread list lock mutator lock
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] All threads:
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] DALVIK THREADS (11):
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "JDWP" prio=5 tid=4 Runnable
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c6a9d0 self=0xacc0a400
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=24589 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb1152920
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=2 stm=10 core=0 HZ=100
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0xb1056000-0xb1058000 stackSize=1014KB
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc 00572f1e  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+238)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 0053f30e  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+526)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 0053c30b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+75)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 0055befb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art14DumpCheckpoint3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+1115)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 005521be  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList13RunCheckpointEPNS_7ClosureE+590)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 00551d32  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEb+962)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 00528168  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState14DumpAllThreadsERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEPNS_6ThreadE+424)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #07 pc 00527eb6  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+1078)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #08 pc 0051822b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEPKc+155)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #09 pc 0011a5b3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD1Ev+1747)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #10 pc 0039b74d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState24AcquireJdwpTokenForEventEy+733)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #11 pc 0039acf3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState29SendRequestAndPossiblySuspendEPNS0_9ExpandBufENS0_17JdwpSuspendPolicyEy+211)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #12 pc 003a0ec9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState16PostClassPrepareEPNS_6mirror5ClassE+1705)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #13 pc 001c2a85  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3Dbg16PostClassPrepareEPNS_6mirror5ClassE+53)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #14 pc 001689fc  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11DefineClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcjNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEERKNS_7DexFileERKNS9_8ClassDefE+1116)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #15 pc 001683e9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker26FindClassInPathClassLoaderERNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_6ThreadEPKcjNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEEPPNS8_5ClassE+1865)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #16 pc 0016979b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker9FindClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEE+1163)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #17 pc 005a7a7a  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier12RegTypeCache12ResolveClassEPKcPNS_6mirror11ClassLoaderE+186)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #18 pc 005a742d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier12RegTypeCache4FromEPNS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEPKcb+701)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #19 pc 005a70fd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier12RegTypeCache14FromDescriptorEPNS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEPKcb+77)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #20 pc 005862ed  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier26ResolveClassAndCheckAccessEj+173)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #21 pc 005895aa  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier25CodeFlowVerifyInstructionEPj+10970)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #22 pc 00585f96  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier20CodeFlowVerifyMethodEv+358)
07-21 14:47:48.256 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #23 pc 00581c9d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier14VerifyCodeFlowEv+973)
07-21 14:47:48.257 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #24 pc 0057da56  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier6VerifyEv+854)
07-21 14:47:48.257 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #25 pc 0057c742  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier12VerifyMethodEPNS_6ThreadEjPKNS_7DexFileENS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEENS7_INS8_11ClassLoaderEEEPKNS4_8ClassDefEPKNS4_8CodeItemEPNS_9ArtMethodEjPNS_17CompilerCallbacksEbNS_11LogSeverityEbPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNSO_11char_traitsIcEENSO_9allocatorIcEEEE+226)
07-21 14:47:48.257 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #26 pc 0057c1c7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier13VerifyMethodsILb0EEENS1_11FailureDataEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_11ClassLinkerEPKNS_7DexFileEPKNS8_8ClassDefEPNS_21ClassDataItemIteratorENS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEENSG_INSH_11ClassLoaderEEEPNS_17CompilerCallbacksEbNS_11LogSeverityEbPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNSP_11char_traitsIcEENSP_9allocatorIcEEEE+791)
07-21 14:47:48.257 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #27 pc 0057b1f9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier11VerifyClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFileENS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEENS7_INS8_11ClassLoaderEEEPKNS4_8ClassDefEPNS_17CompilerCallbacksEbNS_11LogSeverityEPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNSJ_11char_traitsIcEENSJ_9allocatorIcEEEE+921)
07-21 14:47:48.257 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #28 pc 0057a4b9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8verifier14MethodVerifier11VerifyClassEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_6mirror5ClassEPNS_17CompilerCallbacksEbNS_11LogSeverityEPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNSA_11char_traitsIcEENSA_9allocatorIcEEEE+841)
07-21 14:47:48.257 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #29 pc 00174386  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11VerifyClassEPNS_6ThreadENS_6HandleINS_6mirror5ClassEEENS_11LogSeverityE+2102)
07-21 14:47:48.257 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #30 pc 0017a406  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker15InitializeClassEPNS_6ThreadENS_6HandleINS_6mirror5ClassEEEbb+326)
07-21 14:47:48.257 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #31 pc 00158dde  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker17EnsureInitializedEPNS_6ThreadENS_6HandleINS_6mirror5ClassEEEbb+222)
07-21 14:47:48.257 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #32 pc 001b60da  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL17GetFieldValueImplEyyyPNS_4JDWP9ExpandBufEb+1866)
07-21 14:47:48.257 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #33 pc 001b667e  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3Dbg19GetStaticFieldValueEyyPNS_4JDWP9ExpandBufE+78)
07-21 14:47:48.257 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #34 pc 003a4c5d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWPL12RT_GetValuesEPNS0_9JdwpStateEPNS0_7RequestEPNS0_9ExpandBufE+141)
07-21 14:47:48.257 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #35 pc 003a2ea4  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState14ProcessRequestEPNS0_7RequestEPNS0_9ExpandBufEPb+1044)
07-21 14:47:48.257 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #36 pc 003ab570  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState12HandlePacketEv+192)
07-21 14:47:48.257 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #37 pc 00678df3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP12JdwpAdbState15ProcessIncomingEv+1139)
07-21 14:47:48.257 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #38 pc 003ab9d1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState3RunEv+593)
07-21 14:47:48.257 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #39 pc 003aae50  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWPL15StartJdwpThreadEPv+48)
07-21 14:47:48.257 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #40 pc 00074fe2  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+210)

07-21 14:47:48.259 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 00077f51  /system/lib/libc.so (__rt_sigtimedwait+33)
07-21 14:47:48.259 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 000289df  /system/lib/libc.so (sigwait+95)
07-21 14:47:48.259 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 0052eaeb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9SignalSet4WaitEv+59)
07-21 14:47:48.259 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 0052e4b7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art13SignalCatcher13WaitForSignalEPNS_6ThreadERNS_9SignalSetE+215)

                                                                      --------- beginning of crash
07-21 14:47:48.262 24583-24589/com.example.mahya.myapplication A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 24589 (JDWP)

                                                                       [ 07-21 14:47:48.262  1282: 1282 W/         ]
                                                                       debuggerd: handling request: pid=24583 uid=10073 gid=10073 tid=24589
```

Comment: show your log file

Comment: show Log please

Comment: Also post code for RecyclerViewAdapter

Comment: I Edited my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disabled the `Instant run` in Android Studio and the problem went away!